# PermGen size error while generating Cobertura Report

Tags: java, maven, mockito, cobertura, powermockito

I ram running into issue where my application throws PermGen size error whenever I generate `cobertura report` using this command `clean cobertura:cobertura`. I have the tried almost everything such as the following:

- Increase permgen size in sts.ini
- Increase permgen size in jdk vm argumemts by going into Windows -> Preferences 
  -> Java -> Installed JREs -> click jdk -> edit and on the vm args
- Increase permgen size in maven.bat file
- Some in stackOverFlow recommended to mention the version in surefire plugin and I have that in place already

None of the above is helping me at all. I am using Mock/PowerMock objects a lot in my JUnit test cases.  Maven test runs perfectly fine.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tried to change sts.ini, I'm assuming you are running it from inside STS. Even when Maven is kicked off by STS, it runs in a separate process from STS, so changing sts.ini wouldn't help. you need to set the MAVEN_OPTS with the increased permgen size in the run configuration for the mvn job.

Comment: you are correct, after changing it I realized that it's not gonna work as you mentioned. Do you mean for cobertura:cobertura job I should increase the size?

Comment: Yes. Presumably you have a run configuration in STS to run 'mvn clean cobertura:cobertura'. That config is where you need to configure the MAVEN_OPTS.

Comment: Will it be under JRE in the VM arguments?

Comment: It will be under the Environment tab (the last one I think).

Comment: OK, so before I do that I had already done this in maven.bat file set MAVEN_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m. Do you think these two are the same thing?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I don't think Eclipse kicks off maven by maven.bat (or mvn.bat). It likely directly invokes maven's java main.

Answer (score 1):

set  MAVEN_OPTS.

Value will be: -Xms1024m -Xmx3000m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx3000m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m" //unix

set MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx3000m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m" //window
```